# Post Condition Failed on Sitecore 9 Content Delivery Server

Tags: content-management, content-delivery

The CD version of Sitecore 9 was installed on our CD server. The error below is typically seen with a SwitchMasterToWeb.config file issue in previous versions:

Post condition failed 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Post condition failed

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Post condition failed]
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ResultNotNull(T result, String message)
>   +85    Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name) +86    Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabases() +121    Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.Initialize() +110    (Object
>   , Object[] ) +120    Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs
>   args) +479    (Object , Object[] ) +71
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +479
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +161
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +767
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +583
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +169
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +396
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +333
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Post condition failed]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +124    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +700

In this case, with Sitecore 9 we are getting this error with the CD version. Configuration role for CM is set to "ContentManagement" with CD being "ContentDelivery".

To my understanding, this is all you need to do to have your CD instance all setup since there is no longer a *SwitchMasterToWeb.config* in Sitecore 9.

Am I missing something? Any ideas or anyone seen this before on a CD instance with Sitecore 9?

Comment: Did you get chance to have a look at this blog post from jammykam on configuring roles on Sitecore 9 ?  https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/rules-based-configuration/

Comment: I did. Looked through and that's how I made my change to "ContentManagement" and "ContentDelivery" for the roles from "Standalone". Again, I believe that is all that is needed, but no-go for now.

Comment: @TobyGutierrez if this question is now answered, can you mark the answer please?

Comment: I want to also note that this is a very ambiguous error. This can happen if the configuration of the core db is missing in the Sitecore.config. This happened to us when our transforms went haywire. it was not an easy thing to track down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by redeploying my latest code with "ContentManagement" in place for the CM server configuration role and "ContentDelivery" in place for the CD server configuration role. When the deploy finished as successful it was only then that everything started working. Apparently, simply modifying in the Web.configs, via patch file of course, and doing a recycle did not do the trick for me. Happy coding!

Comment: Well, you can't patch the `Web.config` file and thereby the app settings, so that might have been why :)

Comment: My apologies. I meant a .config transform via Slow Cheetah.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, the cause of this error is diverse.

The error message appears when configuration define a database that is not configured or available in the environment.

I had this issue with Sitecore module UrlRewrite.
Please make sure that:

> Hi.UrlRewrite.Prefetch.Master.config

is disabled in CD enviroment.

Comment: And that was exactly the case with my deployment when adding the UrlRewrite module.  I noticed the configs were not installed on my CDs and I copied them there.  Once I disabled that one, happiness ensued.  Thanks so much for that answer!

Comment: I forget to change <add key="role:define" value="Standalone" /> after my testing is done.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had the same error when I delivered Unicorn configs to CD server.
I removed all Unicorn configs from CD and added Unicorn folder with configs to my `pubxml`:

```
<Target Name="ConfigFiles" BeforeTargets="ExcludeFilesFromPackage">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="App_Config\Include\Unicorn">
        <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
      </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
      <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="App_Config\Include\*.disabled">
      </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
      <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="App_Config\Include\*.example">
      </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
      <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="App_Config\Include\*.exclude">
      </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it by removing the Unicorn.DataProvider.config file from the CD environment. This config file contains the following section:

```
<sitecore>
  <databases>
      <database id="master">
```

... which causes Sitecore to look for a master database, which in turn causes the exception.

Comment: As stated in Unicorn.DataProvider.config; `This file should be removed in ANY deployed instance (CE or CD) that does not act as a source for serialized item updates.`

Comment: Thanks Andres it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed the issue on our CD server by running the following Script in powershell after having running unicorn sync.

Remove-Item -Path "$WebsiteDir\$WebsiteDir\App_Config\Include\Unicorn" -Force -Recurse -Verbose

Apparently leaving it on the CMS server works, but not the CD.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore removed core db references from [v9.1](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/core-database.html). If there is a reference of core db in a custom configuration, Sitecore will throw "Post condition failed" exception.

In order to fix it, core db reference needs to be removed from the custom configuration.
One place where core database may be used in Sitecore 9 and below is .

http://www.nehemiahj.com/2021/06/sitecore-post-condition-failed.html